# SQL Server: Attempting to output a count with a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a statement and just a bit puzzled what is the best way to put it together. So I am doing a `UNION` on a number of tables and then from there I want to produce as the output a count for the `UserID` within that day.

So I will have numerous tables union such as:

```
Order ID, USERID, DATE, Task Completed.
UNION
Order ID, USERID, DATE, Task Completed
etc
```

Above is layout of the table which will have 4 tables union together with same names.

Then statement output I want is for a count of `USERID` that occurred within the `last 24 hours`.

So output should be:

```
USERID--- COUNT OUTPUT-- DATE
```

I was attempting a `WHERE` statement but think the output is not what I am after exactly, just thinking if anyone can point me in the right direction and if there is alternative way compared to the `union`? Maybe a joint could be a better alternative, any help be appreciated.

I will eventually then put this into a `SSRS` report, so it gets updated daily.

Comment: You've forgotten postgres and oracle.

Comment: @Strawberry I must admit your comments are hilarious :)

Comment: You need to GROUP BY the user ID and day.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
select USERID, count(*) as [COUNT], cast(DATE as date) as [DATE]
from 
(select USERID, DATE From SomeTable1
 union all
 select USERID, DATE From SomeTable2
 ....
) t
where DATE <= GETDATE() AND DATE >= DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE())
group by USERID, cast(DATE as date)
```

Comment: Would there be another statement, if I want it day by day instead of last 24 hours, so a count user1 did on 27/05/2015 and then user1 did on 26/05/2015

Comment: Just filter out in where clause with appropriate predicate. For example for interval `where DATE <= GETDATE() AND DATE >= '20150101'` All data from new year.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `union all` rather than `union`.  Second, you need to aggregate and use `count distinct` to get what you want:

So, the query you want is something like:

```
select count(distinct userid)
from ((select date, userid
       from table1
       where date >= '2015-05-26'
      ) union all
      (select date, userid
       from table2
       where date >= '2015-05-26'
      ) union all
      (select date, userid
       from table3
       where date >= '2015-05-26'
      )
     ) du
```

Note that this hardcodes the date.  In SQL Server, you would do something like:

```
date >= cast(getdate() - 1 as date)
```

And in MySQL

```
date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
```

EDIT:

I read the question as wanting a single day.  It is easy enough to extend to all days:

```
select cast(date as date) as dte, count(distinct userid)
from ((select date, userid
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select date, userid
       from table2
      ) union all
      (select date, userid
       from table3
      )
     ) du
group by cast(date as date) 
order by dte;
```

Comment: This looks to be counting users, not entries per user per day.

Answer (score 1):

For even more readability, you could use a CTE:

```
;WITH cte_CTEName AS(
SELECT UserID, Date, [Task Completed] FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT UserID, Date, [Task Completed] FROM Table2
etc
)

SELECT COUNT(UserID) AS [Count] FROM cte_CTEName
WHERE Date <= GETDATE() AND Date >= DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I think `UNION ALL` is better for here ;).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve...

```
Select
    UserID,
    Date,
    Count(1)
from 
    (Select *
     from table1
    Union All
     Select *
     from table2
    Union All
     Select *
     from table3
    Union All
     Select *
     from table4
    ) a
Group by 
    Userid,
    Date
```